# PHP Deprecated: mysql_connect():

Tags: php, mysql

I have an outdated php/mysql script that isn't working, due to a server software upgrade.

Here are some lines from the error log:

```
[03-Apr-2017 04:05:16 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead start.php on line 18
[03-Apr-2017 04:05:16 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Function mysql_numrows() is deprecated in library.php on line 135
```

This is line 18 onwards

```
$connection=mysql_connect($sqlserver,$db_login,$db_pass) or die('Could not connect to the database server'); 
$db = mysql_select_db($db_name, $connection) or die ("Unable to select database."); 


$sql="SELECT IP,Date FROM users WHERE IP='$IP' ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 1";
```

and this is line 135 onwards

```
for($i=0;$i<mysql_numrows($result);$i++){
        for($j=0;$j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++){
                        $ranges[$i][mysql_field_name($result,$j)] = mysql_result($result,$i,mysql_field_name($result,$j));
                    }//end inner loop
                }//end outer loop
```

I am not a programmer, can this be solved with a find replace?

If the changes don't work, what further information would be needed?

Thanks!

Comment: It can't be solved just with find and replace. You have to swap to mysqli_* or PDO which does not have the same syntax.

Comment: `mysql_numrows()` isn't even a core function; it's missing an underscore `mysql_num_rows()` for one thing.

Comment: @Sakuto: I guess OP meant this when saying `find and replace`.

Comment: These are only warnings, not errors. These are not the reason why your script does not work. And no, transitioning over to mysqli or PDO cannot be done via search and replace.

Comment: _If the changes don't work, what further information would be needed?_ Well you could start by telling us how much you are prepared to pay for the necessary recoding

Comment: You might try https://www.phpclasses.org/blog/package/9199/post/3-Smoothly-Migrate-your-PHP-Code-using-the-Old-MySQL-extension-to-MySQLi.html but if you are not a programmer I can only offer you good luck and say. Make sure you backup your databases before trying this

Answer (score -2):

With the new [mysqli_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) there are 4 arguments, the first 3 are the same as mysql_connect - $host, $login, $password and the 4th is $db.

This omits the need to include

```
$db = mysqli_select_db($db_name, $connection);
```

I would suggest creating a function

```
function ConnectToDB(){
     return mysqli_connect($host, $login, $pass, $db);
}
```

You can then replace all of your mysql_connects with a call to this function.

```
ConnectToDB();
```

Comment: This in no way solves this OP's whole problem it only moves the error to the first attempt to query the database as all database access calls wil be based on a deprecated `mysql_` api

Comment: a) This is not the only change necessary b) Which part of `I am not a programmer, can this be solved with a find replace?` did you not understand?

Comment: The question has entirely changed upon my answering

Comment: No, been the same question all along, only formatting has changed

Comment: You can see the edit history ([link to initial version](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43368037/1)), it has not... only formatting changes to code blocks.